# Remove gray line between UITableViewCell's

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created custom TableViewCell for my UITableView:

```
class DialogCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var dialog: Dialog? {
        didSet {
            setupDialog()
            if let seconds = dialog?.message!["timestamp"] {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupDialog() {
        ... 
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        ...
    }
        
        override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            addSubview(timeLabel)
            addSubview(profileImageView)
            
            timeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 140, y: 65, width: 100, height: 30)
            profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 20, width: 80, height: 80)
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
}
```

And I need change cell's background color on select:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = dialogsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .pink
        ...
    }
```

But I have some gray lines.

I add those code to viewDidLoad():

```
dialogsTableView.separatorColor = .clear
dialogsTableView.separatorStyle = .none
dialogsTableView.register(DialogCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellid)
dialogsTableView.backgroundColor = .black
```

But it's not working.
What a problem? Thank You

UPD: Gray line appears after clicking on the cell.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know you have tried this via code but also try using interface. Try the following solution:
Open the attributes inspector for your table view as shown below:

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Now select separator Value as none.

If it still does not work use "debug view hierarchy" by pressing the button shown below while the app is running and on the respective screen. This will allow you to see how your views are laid out and narrow down exactly where the problem lies.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Debug view hierarchy helps me! Thank You!

Comment: You are Welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try 'Debug view hierarchy' and find the problem.

My selectedBackgroundView color was gray. And I reassigned selectedBackgroundView:

```
let backView = UIView(frame: selectedCell.frame)
    backView.backgroundColor = .pink
    selectedCell.selectedBackgroundView = backView
```

selectedBackgroundView is in the middle. Thank [Asim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4732793/asim) for idea.

[image]